# jQuery — hasClass in if statement not playing nicely

Tags: jquery, css

I hope I'm not doing something silly here but I'm sure I understand this alright. Here's my code:

```
<body class="someClass">Hi</body>

if($(body).hasClass("someClass")){
   alert("yo");
}
```

For some reason it just doesn't work for some reason, what am I doing wrong?

I've put a jsfiddle of it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uqRhZ/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Body needs to be a string and you probably want the code to execute when the document is ready.

```
$(function(){
   if ($('body').hasClass('someClass')) {
      alert('yo');
   }
});
```

Comment: My bad. I've been coding for 12 hours straight and had a if statement for window directly above it. Window doesnt get stringed, so it was throwing me off.

Answer (score 3):

You were missing the string delimiters, jQuery was looking for a *variable* named 'body', not the body *element*. Use:

```
if($('body').hasClass("someClass")){
       alert("yo");
    }
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uqRhZ/1/).

Also, incidentally, in your [original demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uqRhZ/) you were using MooTools, not jQuery (check the drop-down on the left hand side to load the right library).