# jquery if statement and hasClass?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am using wordpress and a plugin called advanced ajax page loader.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-ajax-page-loader/

I am somewhat familiar with php, javascript and jquery, but not an expert by any means. I have the following block of code that excludes certain pages from loading in ajax and it works great.

```
jQuery(scope + "a").click(function(event){
    //if its not an admin url, or doesnt contain #
    if (  this.href.indexOf(AAPLhome) >= 0 && this.href.indexOf('/wp-') < 0 && this.href.indexOf('#') < 0 && this.href.indexOf('/search') < 0 && this.href.indexOf('/2013') < 0 && this.href.indexOf('/2012') < 0 && this.href.indexOf('/2011') < 0 && this.href.indexOf('/feed') < 0 && this.href.indexOf('/portfolio') < 0 && this.href.indexOf('/store') < 0 ){
        // stop default behaviour
        event.preventDefault();
});
```

As you can see I am excluding pages with certain strings in their url.

However I need to target the homepage link and by inserting the home url this way, all pages contain the home url so they are all excluded. I want to be able to insert a hasClass statement in this block of code so I can exclude a link that has a class of 'homelink'.

This following gave me an error of this.hasClass is not a function.

```
this.hasClass('homelink')
```

So I must be doing something wrong but I'm darned if I know what.

I have tried looking at these links but didn't get much out of it.

[Jquery hasClass + If Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051373/jquery-hasclass-if-statement)

[jQuery — hasClass in if statement not playing nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345374/jquery-hasclass-in-if-statement-not-playing-nicely)

http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Comment: wrap this in $(). "$(this).hasClass('homelink')"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap `this` in `$()`

```
$(this).hasClass('homelink');
```

`this` in that case is a DOMElement and dom elements don't have a `hasClass` method. By passing `this` to `$()`, it becomes a jQuery object which does have the `hasClass` method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kevin. Do I just insert it at the end of my if statement?

Comment: Yes, or at the beginning. I would do it at the beginning so that it is visible before the long list of `&&`'s

Comment: Thanks, it fixed my errors. Only thing is it's working backwards. Guess I need to insert a ! somewhere.

Comment: Yes because it returns true if it has the class, so you would need to negate it, or do `=== false`

Comment: Ok i added the === false and it works perfect now. Thanks so much for your time. I just don't get why I needed to use the === false, it's supposed to exclude if the condition is true.

Comment: If you need to exclude if it's true, you have to make it false if it's true. so, you need either `!$(this).hasClass('homelink')` (my preferred) or `$(this).hasClass('homelink') === false`

Answer (score 0):

Another method with the `:not()` selector:

```
jQuery(scope + "a:not(.homelink)").click(function(event){
```